# Grails stored procedure result is not updated

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

In my grails application, i am calling a stored procedure that will return hundreds of records, After the stored-proc call, I need to send records back to the UI in json format. But, hibernate continues to see the old object after the stored proc is complete.

I am sending different params but it gives the old data only, in MySql Editor stored proc working fine with the reuired params

Can any one help me to fix this issue

**Edit**

Code in Service to get Result

```
Sql sql =  new Sql(dataSource)
def compareBaselineInfo = sql.rows('{call GetBaselinesData(?, ?)}', [projectId, versionIds])        
sql.close();
log.debug('Compare Baseline SP Data :: '+compareBaselineInfo)
```

In Controller

```
def compareData = projectService.compareBaselines(projectDetails.id, params.versionId) as JSON
render(view:"/project/projectViewBaseline", model:[projectDetails: projectDetails, info:compareData.encodeAsJavaScript()])
```

Comment: Could you give us some code snippet of how do you call the stored procedure and you handle results ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi I added my code snippets in Question part

Comment: how are you loading the objects after the SP?

Comment: i simply get the result set and converted to json

Comment: what is your cache configuration here in general like.  e.g. are you using `cache:true` calls in your service or are you using hibernate caching settings in `DataSource.groovy`?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap it with [withNewSession](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/withNewSession.html)? Maybe it's hibernate cache.